# python: detecting a cycle in networkX

Tags: python, loops, networkx, cycle, feedback

As the title implies, I'm trying to write a function that will calculate the number of cycles any inputted node is part of. I found a helpful [video](https://www.educative.io/page/11000001/60001) which explains the theory behind an algorithm to find cycles, but I'm having trouble understanding how to implement it using networkX rather than the data structure that site is using. I couldn't understand the white/grey/etc set concept as well to traverse the network and find cycles.

My function parameters/structure:

```
def feedback_loop_counter(G, node):
    c = 0
    calculate all cycles in the network
    for every cycle node is in, increment c by 1
    return c
```

The network has input and output nodes too, and I'm unclear how those play into calculating cycles

This is my input network:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.DiGraph()
molecules = ["CD40L", "CD40", "NF-kB", "XBP1", "Pax5", "Bach2", "Irf4", "IL-4", "IL-4R", "STAT6", "AID", "Blimp1", "Bcl6", "ERK", "BCR", "STAT3", "Ag", "STAT5", "IL-21R", "IL-21", "IL-2", "IL-2R"]
Bcl6 = [("Bcl6", "Bcl6"), ("Bcl6", "Blimp1"), ("Bcl6", "Irf4")]
STAT5 = [("STAT5", "Bcl6")]
IL_2R = [("IL-2R", "STAT5")]
IL_2 = [("IL-22", "IL-2R")]
BCR = [("BCR", "ERK")]
Ag = [("Ag", "BCR")]
CD40L = [("CD40L", "CD40")]
CD40 = [("CD40", "NF-B")]
NF_B = [("NF-B", "Irf4"), ("NF-B", "AID")]
Irf4 = [("Irf4", "Bcl6"), ("Irf4", "Pax5"), ("Irf4", "Irf4"), ("Irf4", "Blimp1")]
ERK = [("ERK", "Bcl6"), ("ERK", "Blimp1"), ("ERK", "Pax5")]
STAT3 = [("STAT3", "Blimp1")]
IL_21 = [("IL-21", "IL-21R")]
IL_21R = [("IL-21R", "STAT3")]
IL_4R = [("IL-4R", "STAT6")]
STAT6 = [("STAT6", "AID"), ("STAT6", "Bcl6")]
Bach2 = [("Bach2", "Blimp1")]
IL_4 = [("IL-4", "IL-4R")]
Blimp1 = [("Blimp1", "Bcl6"), ("Blimp1", "Bach2"), ("Blimp1", "Pax5"), ("Blimp1", "AID"), ("Blimp1", "Irf4")]
Pax5 = [("Pax5", "Pax5"), ("Pax5", "AID"), ("Pax5", "Bcl6"), ("Pax5", "Bach2"), ("Pax5", "XBP1"), ("Pax5", "ERK"), ("Pax5", "Blimp1")]
edges = Bcl6 + STAT5 + IL_2R + IL_2 + BCR + Ag + CD40L + CD40 + NF_B + Irf4 + 
ERK + STAT3 + IL_21 + IL_21R + IL_4R + STAT6 + Bach2 + IL_4 + Blimp1 + Pax5
G.add_nodes_from(molecules)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
sources = ["Ag", "CD40L", "IL-2", "IL-21", "IL-4"]
targets = ["XBP1", "AID"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write my answer under the assumption you are interested in "simple cycles", that is, cycles whose only repeated node is the first/last node.

Take those nodes that have edges to a node `u` (the "input nodes").  Then use the networkx command [all_simple_paths](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html?highlight=all_simple_paths) to find all simple paths from `u` to each of the input nodes.  Each of these becomes a simple cycle.

Comment: Did it this way, seems like it gives good output after I check the network by hand too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The idea to find cycles is to do a [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and while you do it, remember which nodes you already saw and the path to them. If you happen to visit a node you already saw, then there is a cycle, and you can find it by concatenating paths.

Try writing some code to do that, and open a new question with that code if you get stuck